# Pivot join with two columns having varchar datatype in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot-table

I need to use pivot to create time table from the following data:

[image]

I'm using this query

```
select 
    start_time, end_time, s.subj_name, tt.dd
from 
    time_table tt 
inner join 
    subj s on tt.subjid = s.subjid
```

I am able to pivot my result to

[image]

I used following SQL code to do that:

```
--Declare necessary variables
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT @PivotColumns = COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(dd)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(dd)
      FROM time_table tt
      WHERE divid = 1 AND tt.active = 1) AS PivotExample

SELECT @PivotColumns

--Create the dynamic query with all the values for 
--pivot column at runtime
SET   @SQLQuery = 
    N'SELECT start_time,end_time, ' +   @PivotColumns + ' 
    FROM [dbo].[time_table]  
    PIVOT( SUM(subjid) 
          FOR dd IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS P' 

SELECT   @SQLQuery

--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Do help me out to get subjectname as value instead of subjectid

Answer (score 0):

Since you are pivoting a VARCHAR, you can't use `SUM`, but have to use `MAX` or `MIN`

Try instead:

```
SET   @SQLQuery = 
    N'SELECT start_time,end_time, ' +   @PivotColumns + ' 
    FROM [dbo].[time_table]  
    PIVOT( MAX(subjectname) 
          FOR dd IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS P'
```

Comment: I have tried to make it MAX(subjectname) but subjectname belongs to different table so to retrive we need to ahve join as i shown in second query.So i am not able to execute it.
`SET   @SQLQuery =  `
 `   N'SELECT start_time,end_time, ' +   @PivotColumns + '  `
    FROM [dbo].[time_table]  tt inner join subj s
 on tt.subjid=s.subjid and divid=1
    PIVOT( MAX(s.subj_name) 
`          FOR dd IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS P'  `

Comment: Could you put everything into a CTE and then pivot the CTE results?

Answer (score 0):

Found answer for it which provides simpler way to get it. 
[click to get answer](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1107472/Pivot-columns-in-ms-SQL)